# Would avoiding Nanika indefinately would stop Nanika's wish granting power?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In Hunter x Hunter, one of the rules of [Nanika/Alluka](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Alluka_Zoldyck)'s power is:

> If Alluka is making requests from a particular person, they cannot be moved over to another person mid-way. Therefore if that particular person disappears such as concealing themselves, Alluka is unable to make requests to anybody else.

When Tsubone disappeared from Alluka's sight, Nanika was not able to give her wishes. So therefore, if the target of Nanika's wishes is never seen by Alluka/Nanika again, theoretically, would that be able to stop Nanika from using the wish granting powers?

(This does not include Killua's ability to give Nanika 'orders'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All evidence thus far supports this understanding but it is clear from the story that not everything about her powers is understood.  For instance, what if the person dies before being given the subsequent requests?  This means, therefore, that would stop her powers unless there are additional rules that have yet to be stated to us.